# grails -version FATAL ERROR in native method

Tags: grails, version

I'm trying to get grails version, but getting error all the time. OS: windows server 2012 and windows 8. I suspect that the port is busy, and I can't release it - need another exit from situation
So, I'm doing something like this in command line:

```
{PATH_TO_/bin/grails.bat} -version
```

The result is:

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]
```

So.. what can I do with it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve problem I've just set `JAVA_OPTS`

with

`-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_shmem,server=y,suspend=n`

[Documentation link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html)